# Collapse large header with pagecontroller

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uipageviewcontroller

I currently have a viewcontroller with a large header, set with `self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true`. In this viewcontroller I have a container with a `UIPageViewController`. Each viewcontroller of the UIPageViewController is a `UICollectionViewController`.

Can I collapse the large title when scrolling in the `UICollectionViewController`?